# Determining and proving real roots with multiplicities

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I'm having some issues regarding multiplicities in terms of determining and proving how many roots there are for a function.

Take for instance: $x^3 - 3x + 2$.

We can see that $\ f'(x) > 0, \ x\in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$ and that $\ f'(x) < 0, \ x\in(-1, 1)$. Since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing or decreasing on those intervals there can be at most one root in each interval. Upon further analysis it is clear that since $f(-3) = -16$ and $f(-1) = 4$ so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f(x)$ has a real root for $x \in (-3, -1)$.

However if we look at $f(-1) = 4$ and $f(1) = 0$ we can't say whether there is a root here. Likewise for $x \in (1, \infty)$. My question is that I am not sure what to say about the number of roots at the multiplicity and how to prove such existence.

Clearly $f(1) = 1 - 3 + 2 = 0$ is a root. Not sure how to go on from there.

Comment: Hint: $\;f'(1)=0\,$ as well.

Comment: Do I use the theorem which says since $f(1) = f'(1) = 0$ but since $f''(1) = 6$ this must be a root of multiplicity 2? We haven't done this in class, is there any other way to show the same result?

Comment: Once $f(1)=f'(1)=0$ you know that $1$ is a root of multiplicity *at least* $2$. Since you already determined that there is a root in $(-3,-1)\,$, and since there are at most $3$ real roots in all, you are done. Without derivatives, once you found the root $x=1$ you could factor out $x-1$ and then you are left with a quadratic that is straightforward to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$f (x)=x^3-x-2x+2$$

$$=x (x-1)(x+1)-2 (x-1)$$

$$=(x-1)(x^2+x-2) $$

$$=(x-1)(x^2-x+2x-2) $$

$$=(x-1)^2 (x+2)$$

Comment: Is it sufficient to just show this? Since there can only be one root on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: $1$ is a double root and $-2$ is a simple root.

Comment: Yes! But is this sufficient to prove the existence of 1 as a double root?

Comment: Yes, because $f (x) $ contains the factor $(x-1)^2$ with exponent $2$(double).